# Why is memcpy from int to char not working?

Tags: c++

I have the hex value `0x48656c6c6f` for which every byte represents the ASCII value of each character in the string `"Hello"`. I also have the a `char` array that I want to insert these values into.

When I had a hex value that was smaller (for example, `0x48656c6c`, which represents `"Hell"`), printing out the `char` array gave the correct output. But the following code prints `"olle"` (in little-endian) but not `"olleH"`. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>                           
#include <cstring>                             

int main()
{
    char x[6] = {0};
    int y = 0x48656c6c6f;

    std::memcpy(x, &y, sizeof y);

    for (char c : x)
        std::cout << c;
}
```

[Demo is here.](http://ideone.com/woCmAy#view_edit_box)

Comment: Compilers have warnings. Use them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I didn't get a warning. I'm compiling with an online compiler.

Comment: Get a real compiler :)  Even a decent online compiler will show warnings. ideone needs to up its game.  G++ says `t.cc:7:13: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]`

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted.  While not particularly challenging to someone with a firm understanding of C/C++ programming, I can see it being a difficult question for someone who comes from a different background.

Comment: @itwasntpete Sorry, I was just printing "Hello", not "Hello World" (that was a force of habit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `int` is 32 bit on your machine, which means that the upper byte of your constant is cut; so, your `int y = 0x48656c6c6f;` is actually `int y = 0x656c6c6f;` (by the way, I think that it counts as signed integer overflow, thus undefined behavior; to have defined behavior here you should use `unsigned int`).

So, on a little endian machine the in-memory representation of y is `6f 6c 6c 65`, which is copied to `x`, resulting in the "olle" you see.

To "fix" the problem, you should use a bigger-sized integer, which, depending on your platform, may be `long long`, `int64_t` or similar stuff. In such a case, be sure to make `x` big enough (`char x[sizeof(y)+1]={0}`) to avoid buffer overflows or to change the `memcpy` to copy only the bytes that fit in `x`.

Also, always use `unsigned` integers when doing these kind of tricks - you avoid UB and get predictable behavior in case of overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Probably `int` is four bytes on your platform.

ideone does show a warning, if there is also an error:
http://ideone.com/TSmDk5

prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7:13: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
prog.cpp:12:5: error: ‘error’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 1):

```
int y = 0x48656c6c6f;
```

`int` is not guaranteeed to store it, probably because your machine is 32-bit. Use `long long` instead

Answer (score 0):

It is because an int is only 4 bytes on your platform and the H is being cut out when you provide a literal that is larger than that.